# jqModal Window Effect goes off when form Submission

Tags: jquery, jqmodal

I am invoking a modal window using jqmodal and in it contains a form. When I try to submit the form, the modal window effect goes off. Is there a way i can retain the effect even when the form refresh happens. Ajax submit is 2 complex because of tapestry elements.

One more requirement is how do i get to load another html in the same AJAX window....

This link shows how its done in thickbox with href attribute
[View Sample](http://www.pixeline.be/experiments/ThickboxToJqModal/)

Answer (score 0):

Using this sample i was able to achieve the task.....

http://www.digitss.com/jquery/thickbox/thickbox_hacked.html